# Grafana successfully Import via grafana.com but no data

Tags: grafana

I have successfully run Grafana locally at port 3000 and then default template and data using `Import via grafana.com` for `1860` and `405` id. But the problem is there is no data available.

[image]

[image]

How do I configure it to load the data?

My default data source:

[image]

Comment: I see datasource is default. Can you confirm what datasource is it and is it connected ?

Comment: @Niceha I have added the screenshot of my default data source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, so I am assuming you have tested the datasource, i.e. on Save & Test you get: Data source is working.
I just imported the same dashboard 1860 and it works for me. Some of the issues which you may like to check are:

1. See if you have installed correct node exporter as per your O.S
2. Check node exporter is running
3. In prometheus you have scrape configuration defined for this node exporter. You can refer to the example here https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/node-exporter/
4. This dashboard shows node exporter resources, and if your node exporter is running on custom port other than 9100 then you need to make the changes accordingly.

If above steps dont help, Best way to troubleshoot is stop prometheus service/script. Check node_exporter port --> configure prometheus.yml to point to this port --> start service/script by passing --config.file=./prometheus.yml explicitly.

The dashboard is fine, I just installed and ran. Also attached the pics for your reference.

[image: Check all active node exporters] You should be able to see atleast 1 node exporter. If nothing is shown means no exporter is sending data. And you know you have to fix the node exporter on that host.
[image: If you get something like this] that means you are not monitoring node exporter data

[image: In settings > variables > node] This should return all your node exporters pushing data to prometheus server. In my case, only localhost is sending.

[image: final dashboard]